# Removing columns from query

Tags: sql-server

I have several tables with 4 columns which are always present, and an indeterminate number of columns generated automatically with random names. Given that "SELECT * EXCEPT xyzcol" doesn't exist, what would be the easiest way to go about retrieving only the automatically-generated columns?

Comment: No, it is not possible to select all columns except one using *. You should not use * to select columns in production. Specify every column by name(and maybe prefex with a table alias), then remove the one you don't want.

Comment: Specifying every column by name is hardly feasible when i have 100+ automatically generated tables, each with 10-50 automatically generated columns with semi-random names. I'm not looking for best practices, just a way to do it.

Comment: Dynamic SQL - perhaps write your queries as Table-valued Functions, then create and execute dynamic SQL to select just the columns you want from the table returned by the function.  So the function returns a SELECT * and the dynamic SQL querying the function adds a column list, which would be less difficult than crafting a large query via strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't know the column names, you should go dynamic.

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @SQL = @SQL+QUOTENAME(COLUMN_NAME)+',' FROM (
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,ORDINAL_POSITION FROM 
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='ADDRESS'
AND ORDINAL_POSITION>4 --SKIPPING FIXED 4 COLUMNS HERE
)A
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION

SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT '+LEFT(@SQL,LEN(@SQL)-1)+ ' FROM [ADDRESS]'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

I will always keep a dynamic script for creating `INSERT` script handy for a quick insert in support days.

Comment: Pretty much spot on what I was looking for, thank you!